# P2 repository for org.eclipse.test bundle

Tags: eclipse, osgi, p2

Where can I find a p2 repository containing org.eclipse.test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test bundles and framework are included in our repos as of 3.7M2 (Sept 2010).  See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=318514 for more details.

Comment: Excellent. An actual contributor :) +1

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a p2 update site for [ETF (Eclipse Testing Framework)](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.test/)

ETF itself doesn't recognize test bundles in p2 repo: "[JUnit4 and the Eclipse Test Framework: Success!](http://eclipse-ruminations.blogspot.com/2010/02/junit4-and-eclipse-test-framework.html)":

> ETF was created before p2. So you just dropped your test bundles into the "plugins" folder of the SDK, launched the SDK specifying the ETF application and test bundle / test class, and off you go.

And ETF looks quite old, with [plan to move to JUnit4](http://wiki.eclipse.org/ETF_JUnit4_Changes) only [recently achieved](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=298619).
It doesn't seem to benefit from the same p2 compliant packaging than the other Eclipse projects.

Comment: That would be a shame, as I'm trying to move a build to Tycho, and needing a local Eclipse SDK for just that feature is not so nice. Any other pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: @Robert: I understand. So far, no other pointers, I ma still looking.

Answer (score 1):

You can create p2 repositories from features and plugins yourself. See the section "Features and Bundles Publisher" in [this](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_publisher.html) link.